# Actix Web 4 always add "Ok" field

Tags: rust, actix-web

Currently, I change actix_web from version 3 to 4.0.0-rc.1 and for every response, it always add "Ok"/"Err" field as below

```
{
   "Ok": [
       "item1",
       "item2"
   ]
}
```

It should return:

```
[
   "item1",
   "item2"
]
```

This is handler for the API

```
pub async fn get_data(db: web::Data<Pool>) -> HttpResponse {
    let res = web::block(move || db_get_data(db)).await;

    match res {
        Ok(data_vec) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(data_vec),
        Err(_) => HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish()
    }
} 

fn db_get_data(db: web::Data<Pool>) -> Result<Vec<String>, ()> { 
    let items = vec!["item1".to_string(), "item2".to_string()];
    Ok(items)
}
```

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Without a [mre] it is impossible to know for sure. One possible shot in the dark is that some API was changed to return a `Result` and you forgot to [handle the result value](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html) properly.

Comment: @E_net4standswithUkraine I just added the handler for my API, could you please check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two layers of `Result`: one from [`actix_web::web::block`](https://docs.rs/actix-web/latest/actix_web/web/fn.block.html) and another from `db_get_data`. Try something like this:

```rust
let res = web::block(move || db_get_data(db)).await;

match res {
    Ok(Ok(data_vec)) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(data_vec),
    _ => HttpResponse::BadRequest().finish(),
}
```